# Left function cancellation implies injectivity

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I am reading the follwing proof below

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Injection_iff_Left_Cancellable

> We want to show that if $f:Y \to Z$ is not injective, then $f$ is not left cancellable. So, assume $\exists y_1 \ne y_2 \in Y: f(y_1)=f(y_2)$
>
> Define: $g_1, g_2:Y \to Y$ as $\forall y \in Y:g_1(y)=y \text{ and } g_2(y) =  \cases{y_2 \text{ if } y = y_1 \\ y \text{ if } y \ne y_1}$. Thus we have $g_1 \ne g_2$ such that $f \circ g_1 = f \circ g_2$.

I am a bit confused about the equality of compositions. Suppose $y = y_1$. Then $f\circ g_1(y) = f\circ g_1(y_1) = f(y_1)$ and $f \circ g_2(y)  = f(y_2)$. Is it necessarily true that $f(y_1) = f(y_2)$ for any $y_1, y_2$? How do we prove these compositions are equal?

Comment: It’s not “for any”. If $f$ is not injective, then there are *specific* $y_1$ and $y_2$ such that $y_1\neq y_2$ but $f(y_1)=f(y_2)$. It is those, and only those two elements, that are specifically named in the definition of $g_1$ and $g_2$.

Comment: I think you have assumed $f(y_1)=f(y_2)$, there is no question of necessity.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, I see: $y_1, y_2$ with certain properties are unique in any context. Thanks. No more questions.

Comment: No, they aren’t necessarily “unique”, but they are *singled out* for the definitions of $g_1$ and $g_2$.

Answer (score 1):

I would have written another proof for the Wiki:

Given $y_1 \neq y_2$ with $f(y_1)=f(y_2)$:

Let $X=\{0,1\}$ and define $g_1: \{0,1\} \to Y$ by $g_1(0) = y_1, g_1(1)=y_2$.

And let $g_2: \{0,1\} \to Y$ be defined by $g_2(0) = g_2(1)=y_1$.

Then clearly $g_1 \neq g_2$ as they have different values on $1$.

But $f(g_1(0)) = f(y_1) =  f(g_2(0))$ and also $f(g_1(1))= f(y_2) = f(y_1) = f(g_2(1))$, so on all of $X$: $f \circ g_1 = f \circ g_2$ and this combination of facts contradicts the left cancellative property of $f$ we assumed at the outset.

Comment: Or you could start with $f(y_1)=f(y_2)$, define $g_1$ and $g_2$ as you do, verify that $fg_1=fg_2$, and use cancellation to conclude that $y_1=y_2$...

Comment: @ArturoMagidin true, a more “positive “ approach.